# How to get \titleformat to display chapter count number?

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead[][][\chaptertitle]{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

This successfully removes the word 'chapter' from the chapter titles. However I want to include the chapter count number as well. Something like '1. Introduction'. How do I do this using titlesec?

Comment: Do you want chapter number and chapter title on separate lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `display` style if you want the chapter label on the same line as the chapter title. Use the default `hang` style, or `block`if you want to centre it. Note `twoside` isn't necessary: it's the default in the `book` class. Also don't load `fancyhdr` if you want to use `titlesec` with the `pagestyles` option, which loads `titleps`, and it may conflict with `fancyhdr`.

Here is a code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, vmargin=25mm, headheight=28pt, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead[][\thechapter.\enspace\chaptertitle][]{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{A First Section}
\lipsum[6-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want all the page numbers centered at the bottom. Also I want the custom heading to be centered, on both odd and even pages.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it like you want?

Comment: thanks! I am trying to achieve the same result using fancyhdr, which i find easier to tweak and more intuitive. Stay tuned for my next question!

Comment: You find the `\leftmark/rightmark:\markboth` system more intuitive that `\sectiontitle`and  `\chaptertitle`?!!!

Comment: ok. Maybe not, these are all equally confusing!

Comment: But, anyway thank you very much for your help! My Latex is up and running! :)

Answer (score 1):

Include `\thechapter.\quad` as part of your title setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be able to do the same for your header.

Comment: Thanks! How would you change the heading \sethead[][][\chaptertitle]{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}} to include that? I can't get it to work for the heading!

Comment: @PintoDoido: Use `\thechapter~\chaptertitle` in the header setting.

Comment: @Werner: For your code, the default `[hand]` style is enough. `[display]` is to be used when chapter label and chapter title are on separate lines.

Comment: it's working now! \sethead[][][\thechapter.\quad\chaptertitle]{\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}

Comment: This is wrong. Try with `\chapter*{Title}`.